# Chat Overflow (Name of people in room overlapping)

Tags: discussion, status-norepro

Just noticed this while chatting with a user...

[image]

The box with the users currently in chat is putting the names over the top of each other so you can't see anything besides a mess of characters.

Firefox 57.0.2 x64, and it makes no difference what size my browser window is.

Is this a bug? Or something silly with client side rendering?

Comment: Do you have a link to that chat room please?

Comment: Sure; https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/70405/discussion-between-user3788685-and-keith

Answer (score 9, accepted):

#### A bug? or something silly with client side rendering?

Something is amiss with your internet connection and it is not rendering avatars - so it is using the user name instead.

It looks like https://www.gravatar.com is blocked at your location.

What it should look like:

[image]

Comment: It Was - just confirmed & it's working elsewhere. Do you have any method to fall back if this is the case rather than a mess of chars?

Comment: @user3788685 No. Other than fixing your connection. Either your route to https://www.gravatar.com/ is not working or you have that domain blocked in your host file, or via some FF extension, or your DNS is borked ...

Comment: It was being blocked by a server in a cache cluster - I've removed it now.